# Iterate over map of `interface{}` and call the same method on each item in Golang

Tags: go, types, interface, iteration, go-map

I am working on a simple Console game to learn Go and got stuck on a seemingly simple issue that would be no problem in other languages, but seems almost impossible in Go.

I have a map of interfaces as a field in struct like this:

```
type Room struct {
    // ...
    Components map[string]interface{}
    // ...
}
```

And I need to iterate over the map and call a `Render()` method on each of the items stored in the map (assuming they all implement `Render()` method. For instance in JS or PHP this would be no problem, but in Go I've been banging my head against the wall the entire day.

I need something like this:

```
for _, v := range currentRoom.Components {
    v.Render()
}
```

Which doesn't work, but when I specify the type and call each item individually by hand, it works:

```
currentRoom.Components["menu"].(*List.List).Render()
currentRoom.Components["header"].(*Header.Header).Render()
```

How can I call the `Render()` method on every item in the map? Or if there is some better/different approach to go about it, please enlighten me, because I'm at the end of my rope here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an interface:

```
type Renderable interface {
   Render()
}
```

Then you can type-assert elements of the map and call Render as long as they implement that method:

```
currentRoot.Components["menu"].(Renderable).Render()
```

To test if something is renderable, use:

```
renderable, ok:=currentRoot.Components["menu"].(Renderable)
if ok {
   renderable.Render()
}
```

Comment: Better yet, define the map as `map[string]Renderable`, if all the  components are renderable